# can I convert audio to MFCC as RGB image and then use the image in CNN for audio classification

Tags: conv-neural-network, librosa, mfcc

I am currently working on audio speech classification and the audios length that I have vary between 5 sec up to 5 min, my question is can I convert my audio to MFCC as RGB image and then use CNN with softmax? does this sounds like a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds rather convoluted ;)

You can skip the RGB part, and just pass the MFCC directly to the CNN.

Comment: well yes i see your point but the problem is that  not all audio have the same length, some are 5 sec while others are 5 min, this is why I added the RGB part so all of them will have the same dimensions.

Comment: Adding RGB doesn't help with that at all. You just take one-second slices, and slide that window over your audio.